# Is it possible to filter a wordpress query with javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a page with a bunch of posts from a basic wordpress query, like this:

```
<?php while($homepageSpellQuery->have_posts()) {
    $homepageSpellQuery->the_post(); ?>
    <div>
       The content
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

And I want that when the user checks a button, only the posts associated with that button show up, but I didn't want to have to reload the page and mage another query, I just want to filter out the existing query. Is this something achievable with javascript?

My current idea is to add classes bases on the filters, and when the user clicks the button, a javascript function hides every post that doesn't have that specific class, but this solution sounds very inefficient to me.

Comment: Yeah, if you already have the information with PHP, then you can use JavaScript on the Client to further parse it.

Comment: Very inefficient in terms of adding the extra classes for the filters, or JavaScript hiding the posts? I don't think it is really. The main inefficiency is loading the extra posts in the first place when you don't want to show them, but if you're filtering existing results then you will have loaded them already.

Comment: @Rup Since this posts only have text and a few svg icons, I thought loading everything at the same time wouldn't be a problem, but I just tested and it is very much a problem haha. Basically, it's too many server requests and javascript event listeners at the same time. I'll have to figure out a way to display everything on the same page, but querying them dynamically, like Facebook and Twitter, I just have 0 ideas how to do that, at the moment

Comment: But client side filtering shouldn't generate more server requests? But happy to defer to what you're seeing.

Comment: I was refering to loading every post at once, which I though wouldn't be a problem.